Confused about this exhance (だれ　じゃ)
Two character are sleeping side by side. Because their difference in size in the same bed, one chapter feet leak out the cover and he explains:

すっげえ足が余る

The other character, who is shorter, annoyed, replies this

誰がちびで短足じゃしばくよ

As far I can gather the other character is essentially annoyed that the other is implying they are short so they are like "I'll punch you for calling me short" however, grammar wise I'm kinda confused about what is going on to be honest.
誰 じゃ?

This is the dialectical じゃ which is just the copula (だ). In standard Japanese, the sentence can be converted to something along the lines of:

誰がちびで短足だよ。殴るぞ。

I guess the confusion here stems from misunderstanding じゃ as the one that is a contraction of では, which is honestly understandable given the absence of a comma. But always remember that commas don't carry semantic significance in Japanese (most of the time).
The usage of じゃ over だ is a very common "old guy" trope in anime and manga, regardless of whether or not the character comes from a region that uses this variation. You may read this answer to learn more about this particular instance of yakuwarigo.

By the way, じゃ is modernized spelling of /d͡ʑa/, which was formerly /ⁿd͡ʑa/, which was originally contraction of dea (historical pronunciation: /ⁿd͡ʑea/), which was contraction of de aru (historical pronunciation: /ⁿd͡ʑe aru/). /ⁿd͡ʑa/ was one of standard copulae in around 16th century in standard Japanese.
